# missing ID/ Path on upload

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to upload a file using Symfony2 tutorial : http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

I can choose the file, i can upload it, but the thing is, I'd like to get a unique name for every uploaded file. I tried to do so using this function :

```
public function upload()
{
if (null === $this->file)
{
return;
}
if (null !== $this->tempFilename)
{
    $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->tempFilename;
    if (file_exists($oldFile))
    {
    unlink($oldFile);
    }
}
$this->file->move(
$this->getUploadRootDir(),
$this->id.'.'.$this->path
    );
}
```

At first, I thought this wasn't working, but it appears that $this->id and $this->path are null. I tried again, by replacing this line by

```
    $this->id.'.'.'test'.'.'.$this->path
```

This time, it "worked", for I could upload the file, but all of the files had the same name : ".test."

I have no idea where this come from, since the rest of the entity was generated automatically using doctrine.

```
    /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $path;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add time like

```
$this->id.'.'.time().'.'.$this->path
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't solve the problem : I still cannot access my file. When I look at my database, i see the IDs, but for some reason, they end up as null therefore, zhen I click on the link that should bring me to the file, it brings me to the folder that contains the file. As a teacher, i/d like my student to access directly to the PDF file :)

Comment: does your files are uploaded?

Comment: Yes they are, they all end up in the right folder, but when I click on the link, it brings me inside this folder, instead of bringing me on the file. That is annoying, because my student could get access to all the subjects before they are released

Comment: what is this echoes `$this->id.'.'.'test'.'.'.$this->path` ?

Comment: That's the tricky part: it only echoes ".test.". For some reason, it appears that $id and $path are null, but when I check my database, id is not. id is generated automatically, i can read the value, but for some reason, I can't get them back.

Comment: try to `print_r($this);` and check what you have in `this` object

Comment: Futur\SujetBundle\Entity\Sujet Object ( [id:Futur\SujetBundle\Entity\Sujet:private] => [url:Futur\SujetBundle\Entity\Sujet:private] => [alt:Futur\SujetBundle\Entity\Sujet:private] =>